# How to initialize the onscreenkeyboard on the number view?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Hey, I'm making an app where users should sometimes write numbers.

**Is there a way to display the number view of the onscreen keyboard right away?** So the user won't right "hundred" instead of "100"?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:numeric="integer"
```

use this in your edittext ...

you can also use decimal , signed

for more details http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/numeric-edittext-and-edittext-with-max.html

Answer (score 1):

Check the [InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) attribute of the [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) class. You can set it to `number` so the user can only insert numbers to the EditText. In this case the keyboard should automatically show the number view.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to set the TextView inputType: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setInputType%28int%29 .

An example specifically of asking for a number pad is at http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/some-examples-of-inputtype-on-edittext.html

Answer (score 0):

Put the Below code in to Edittext view. . . .

```
android:numeric="integer"
android:phoneNumber="true"
```

if this tips helps u then vote me. . .